# Localhost and Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation, localhost

I'm runnning the Windows Phone Emulator and want to access the local host of the computer the emulator is running on. "http://localhost" doesn't work as well as using the ip address in the emulator's browser.

So, how can I access the localhost or any other PC available in the local network via the browser of the windows phone emulator?

Thanks
Konrad

Comment: Are you testing it from Internet Explorer? On my emulator I can access http://localhost/ with the default settings.

Comment: I'm testing it from IE in the Emulator. Default installation ... typing "localhost" or "http://localhost" in the URL field ... nothing happens ... typing the same in my local browser at the host system: localhost is loaded as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange - it normally works. Perhaps some network configuration setting on your box is affecting it? Try running with fiddler too.

Comment: Restarting the PC, sleeping a night, restarting the emulator: Now it works ... no idea what is was.

Comment: This answer is misleading and incorrect for WP8. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149304/windows-phone-8-emulator-access-localhost

Comment: The answer is vague and doesn't mention WP8. The question was about WP7.