# Cannot connect Windows Phone Emulator to Internet when using Wireless adapter on the host

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I’m developing Windows Phone app using VS2012 on Dell XPS 15 laptop with Win8 pro.I read a lot of troubleshooting articles here (specially [Windows Phone 8 emulator can't connect to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159947/windows-phone-8-emulator-cant-connect-to-the-internet)) and in other places on the web and have not managed to solve the issue (see the subject). Note my laptop gets successfully IP using DHCP on both adapters (wireless and wired) and no MAC filtering is set on the router. Here is the story:

1) **Does not work:** When starting WP emulator, it does not get IP from
    router (DHCP)

2) **Works:**

- start over (delete virtual switches and machine in Hyper-v)
- disable wireless adapter
- connect wired adapter to router with cable
- start emulator (it creates machine and switches)
- gets IP and Internet is accessible

3) **Does not work:**

- start over (delete virtual switches and machine in Hyper-v)
- disable wired adapter– windows control panel shows : Bluetooth and
  Wireless enabled and wired disable – no others
- start emulator (it creates machine and switches)
- result:
- a) router log shows “DHCP server received REQUEST”
- b) on the host I see (ipconfig) virtual switch gets IP (vEthernet
  (Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030 Virtual Switch)) – it selected
  as “Windows Phone Emulator External” in virtual machine settings
- c) in emulator network tab of “Additional Tools” window I see adaptors
  with default IP 169.*

3) **Partially works:**

- delete virtual switches
- disable wired adapter– windows control panel shows : Bluetooth and
  Wireless enabled and wired disable – no others
- create internal switch in hyper-v named “Windows Phone Emulator
  Internal Switch” and select it in internal network adapter of virtual
  machine
- enable sharing in wireless adapter (in control panel)
- start emulator as standalone with xde.exe (starting from VS will not
  use right snapshot with deployed app) and does not allow it to
  connect to network – loading takes much more time and after that, OS
  is loading and emulator shows error dialog  “Some functionality maybe
  disables”
- it possible to use emulator with Internet, but device buttons does
  not work – use keyboard shortcuts
  (http://devatheart.azurewebsites.net/2011/06/04/windows-phone-7-emulator-and-physical-keyboard-shortcuts/)
- it cannot be used for debugging – it is good only for showing the app on public ;-)

Comment: [WP8: Emulator has no Internet access](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/28c8316a-80e8-4fd9-b323-c07a2265d069/) the solutions discussed here should solve your prolem. Also see this [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2012/11/27/what-the-hyper-v-wp8-sdk-emulator-and-hyper-v-insights.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your question but this may help.
connect with your wireless network
host the wireless connection using netsh in CMD. an alternative is creating an internal switch sharing your connection with your lan adapter
you can do that with connectify too. 
by now, your PC should show you are both connected to a wireless and lan network.
run the emulator from visual studio and you get connected.