# no internet on windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have installed windows phone 8 SDK and tried running a simple app which embeds a WebBrowser on a page. When I try to run the app in emulator the emulator does not get internet connection. It displays an error message saying "You don't have permission to modify internal Hyper-V network adapter settings required to run the emulator". Im sure my login has admin permissions. My machine is 64bit, hyper v is enabled and Hyper v manager is running, hardware virtualization is enabled in the BIOS settings, DHCP is enabled and its connected to a wired network. I have checked all the system requirements. What ever I do it keeps on giving the same error message. I setup everything in a different machine and tried running the app in that machine. The same error message is displayed in the that machine also. Can anyone tell me how to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

> DHCP is enabled and its connected to a wired network

Can you run ipconfig /all on your host machine and post it here please?

seems you have problem with your DHCP or maybe multiple DHCP and conflict.

Comment: also check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159947/windows-phone-8-emulator-cant-connect-to-the-internet

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your user account as a member of the "Hyper-V Administrators" group on the machine.

Detailed steps:

1. Hit Windows key + Q and search for "local users and groups".  Change the search scope to "Settings".  Click "Edit local users and groups".
2. Expand the "Groups" section.  Right-click on "Hyper-V Administrators" and select "Add to group".
3. Add your user account.

Answer (score 0):

Some connection tools *on the host* can have negative effects when used with the emulator; I found having cisco VPN client installed on the host prevented the emulator from finding the internet. Other VPN clients may have similar side-effects. I simply uninstalled cisco (the inbuilt windows VPN is fine for what I need) and it worked perfectly.

I've also seen problems where it won't find the internet after the host has been suspended / resumed. In *that* scenario, it turned out to be bad network drivers. I installed a dedicated Intel NIC (rather than the on-board NIC on the motherboard) - problem solved.

Basically, Hyper-V is a bit fussy.

Answer (score 0):

try refreshing the hyper-v by unchecking and then checking it again,this worked for me.
Steps:
1.control panel>>programs>>Programs and features>>turn windows features on and off>>hyper-v
2.uncheck it and restart the pc.
3.again go to control panel an check hyper-v and restart the pc again.
the try to run the emulator,should work..

Answer (score 0):

another possible reason is that you did not start vs2013 as admin