# How do I connect to Wireless Network from Windows Phone Emulator in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have come to the point that my Windows phone emulator can not be connected to wireless network.

My system is connected through WLAN. I am getting error:

```
"System.Servicemodel.CommunicationException"
```

How do I connect to Wireless Network?

Comment: It is not possible share net emulator to your device . but yes you can access internet in your emulator. read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2013/08/20/connecting-the-windows-phone-8-emulator-to-web-api-applications-on-a-local-computer.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect your emulator to a different network that the one your computer is connected to, for a simple reason : your emulator isn't a physical device, and therefore does not have it's own network card. It gets it's internet connection from the computer on which the emulator runs. If you really need this connection to test your app, the only way is to test it on a physical device.

Comment: C can you answer me one more question,brother?? I have not enough reputation,upvote the question,so that I can upvote the answer!!the question is that so I am not able to call WCF service from emulator, is it right??

Comment: Well, technically you can because even though your emulator is not physically connected to a network, it's still connected via your computer ! But to be honest, I have never used WCF service before so I don't really know

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Windows Phone 8 emulator can't connect to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159947/windows-phone-8-emulator-cant-connect-to-the-internet) I also suffered a lot from this. The solution that worked for me is deleting the emulator from the hyper v manager and recreating it from visual studio