# Cannot start Windows Phone Emulator (have a trouble with Hyper-V)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, emulation, hyper-v

When I build a app with WP emulator it have a problem.

Can you help me about this.

This error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/etUJd.png

Enable Hyper V, But services not run
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVqg1.jpg

I aready enable Virtual Technology in BIOS.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this: (Enabling BIOS Settings)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

There are more than one BIOS setting to be changed.

And another question: You have Windows 8 Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've started the `Virtual Machine` for the WP emulator to run, from the `Hyper-V Manager`.

Follow the steps from here:

[The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service must be running](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956894(v=ws.10).aspx)

For more have a look at this:

[Windows Phone 8 emulator can't connect to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159947/)