# Windows 10 - VS 2015 - Unable to Start Hyper-V Based Emulators within VMWare Workstation 11 VM

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v

I am unable to start any of the the Hyper-V emulators (VS Android Emulator or any of the Windows Phone Emulators) when operating within a VMWare Workstation version 11 virtual machine.

Attached is how I have configured my VM underlying BIOS.

Also attached is the message I receive when attempting to start any of the emulators.

Hyper-V is installed and the Hyper-V management service is installed and started.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow nested running of one virtual machine (Hyper-V) inside the other (VMWare).

Following steps worked for me:

1. Close VMWare Virtual machine and open *.vmx and add following lines:

   ```
   vmx.allowNested = "TRUE"
   hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE" 
   vhv.enable = "TRUE"
   ```
2. Start Virtual machine (be sure to have at least 2 GB of free memory)
3. Add Hyper-V Role: Under "Control Panel->Programs->Programs and Features" add all Hyper-V components (now Hyper-V Hypervisor should be selectable)
4. Restart the VMWare Virtual machine and open Hyper-V Manager. Follow the instructions in this article: [Windows Phone 8 emulator can't connect to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159947/windows-phone-8-emulator-cant-connect-to-the-internet) to configure the network.

Hope that helps!

Comment: What do you mean "open *.vmx"?

Comment: @godskook: There is a file with the vmx ending in your folder where the virtual machine is saved. Usually it is named like your VM, for example "VS Emulator 5.5-inch Lollipop.vmx". This file you can edit with notepad or any other text editor.