# Loading issue of Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: android, vmware, hyper-v, visual-studio-emulator

I am working on an android application in VMware. I am using Visual Studio Emulator for testing. But it is not loading. It shows an error that 'one of the HyperV component not running'. I already turn on HyperV.

Attached the error alert message below.

Please help me to find a solution.

[Error alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swtB5.png)

Comment: Anyone please suggest solutions.

Comment: Any Idea about this

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following answer. 
You need to allow nested running of one virtual machine (Hyper-V) inside the other (VMWare)
[Windows 10 - VS 2015 - Unable to Start Hyper-V Based Emulators within VMWare Workstation 11 VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057734/windows-10-vs-2015-unable-to-start-hyper-v-based-emulators-within-vmware-wor)