# Hyper-V / Visual Studio Emulator for Android can't connect to network

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v

I'm on Windows 10 Pro x64, using the latest `Visual Studio Emulator for Android` (Jan 2016). I have wired and wireless NICs, the wireless is connected to the Internet, and the wired is disabled to avoid conflicts (as often advised in other answers). I am using DHCP.

I can run the Android VM in both Hyper-V and the emulator.

But the VM cannot connect to the network. Once the Hyper-V virtual switches are created, my host's network fails. To fix it, I manually set the TCP/IP v4 settings for that virtual switch connection - then the host can again see the network, but the guest still cannot.

The [official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx#Network) specify use [of DHCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#ManualNetworkConfig), which is the case (I only use manual settings because it disconnects me).

How do I get both the host and guest to see the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer gave me the clue I needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13230954/3959480).

I was using DHCP on the host, but *on the router itself*, there was an IP address static mapping. Removing that made the problem disappear!