# Getting 404 response from web api

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-7, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

1. I have webapi and method:

   ```
   public class ArticlesController : ApiController
   {
        //
        // GET: api/values
        public IEnumerable<Article> Get()
        {
            using (CollectionsEntities entities = new CollectionsEntities())
            {
                 return entities.Articles.ToList<Article>();
            }
        }
    }
   ```

It works fine, and check it in browser:

[image: webapi works]

2. I create a client:

   ```
   public static class CollectionClient
   {
       private static readonly HttpClient client;

       public static Uri ServerBaseUri
       {
           get { return new Uri("http://localhost:10779/api/"); }
       }

       public static Boolean IsDirty { get; private set; }

       static CollectionClient()
       {
           IsDirty = true;
           client = new HttpClient(new DemoHttpMessageHandler());
       }

       // get all articles
       public static async Task<List<Article>> GetAllArticlesAsync()
       {
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
           Uri serverUril = new Uri(ServerBaseUri, "Articles");            
           var response = await client.GetAsync(serverUril);

           response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

           var articles = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Article>>();
           IsDirty = false;
           return articles;   
       }
   }
   ```

The response gets 404 status code:
[image]

`ID_CAP_NETWORKING` is checked to make sure it can access internet.
Could anybody give me a hand? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have a `windows-phone-7` tag on your post?

Comment: coz I access this web api from a program in windows phone 8 emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have experience with Android but "localhost" for the emulator is probably different than the "localhost" for your PC. Try using the internal subnet IP instead.

Comment: i use 127.0.0.1 instead, still the same, any ideas?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the same thing as the localhost (a loopback address). You need to use something like 192.168.1.x or whatever the local subnet is.

Comment: Here is a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149304/windows-phone-8-emulator-access-localhost that has a detailed answer.

Comment: i use a public api to try, it works.  that proves program is collect, will publish the web api and re-try. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

In windows phone 7.x, the emulator shared the networking of the Host PC, that means:
 we could host services on our PC and access them from our code using `htt://localhost..`

In windows phone 8, the emulator is a virtual machine running under Hyper V, that means:
you cannot access services on your PC using   `htt://localhost..`

you must use the correct host name or raw IP address of our host PC in URIs